# lua cjson encode nil field

Tags: lua, cjson

I have a lua table such as:

```
local _table = {}

_table["name"] = "some user name"    
_table["phone"] = nil

ngx.say(cjson.encode(_table))
```

The ngx.say output as below:

```
{"name":"some user name"}
```

As you can see the phone field in _table has been ignored! How to set encoding-options to include any nil field during cjson encode processing.
Such as:

```
{"name":"some user name", "phone": null}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning `nil` to a table field means that this table field will be treated as unset, i.e. from Lua's point of view it stops existing. CJSON comes with a dedicated value to represent `null`, use that instead:

```
_table["phone"] = cjson.null
```